# Spyder 4.2.3 not showing function variables

Tags: python, spyder

I have seen that this has been an issue in the past, but never seems to have been solved. references to older spyder versions are common, but I haven't seen any relating to v4. (links to discussions: [github](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4154) [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806392/viewing-local-variables-in-spyders-variable-explorer))
When executing a script which calls a function I can not see how to make the function variables visible in the variable explorer. I am using Spyder 4.2.3 installed via Anaconda on a windows 10 machine with all updates installed,
In the variable explorer options menu I have unchecked all the 'exclude' options, I have tried stepping into the function using the debugger, but dont seem to be able to get this to work either.

Edit: When the script runs any variables generated by it display in the variable explorer. Any variable generated by the function called by the script is not displayed. I'm sure it used to be,
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "function variables"? the parameters you pass to the function? for context, could you add a link to where this was already discussed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean the variable explorer frame stays empty instead of displaying all the variables?
You need to make sure the [correct version of spyder-kernels](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/troubleshooting/common-illnesses.html) is installed in the environment Spyder is install in. From the link:

| Spyder | Spyder-Kernels |
| --- | --- |
| 4.0.0-4.0.1 | 1.8.1 |
| 4.1.0-4.1.2 | 1.9.0 |
| 4.1.3 | 1.9.1 |
| 4.1.4 | 1.9.3 |
| 4.1.5-4.1.6 | 1.9.4 |
| 4.2.0 | 1.10.0 |
| 5.0.0-5.0.5 | 2.0.5 |
| 5.1.0-5.1.5 | 2.1.3 |
| 5.2.0-5.2.1 | 2.2.0 |
| 5.2.2 | 2.2.1 |

If using conda:

```
conda activate ENVIRONEMENT-NAME
conda install spyder-kernels=<VERSION>
```

If not using conda, activate the environment however you usually would and run:

```
pip install spyder-kernels==<VERSION>
```